# How do I write join query in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

i m trying to run a HQL query which is giving me error saying:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
UserType of: EntityPack.UserTypeMenu 
[from EntityPack.UserTypeMenu as utm ,EntityPack.UserType as ut 
 where utm.UserType.userTypeId=ut.userTypeId and ut.userTypeDesc like ' %ad%' ]
```

this is the function where i write query :

```
    public ObservableList PostTableusertypemenu(String search, int q) {
            ObservableList data;
            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            List ll=null;
                 ll = pop.UrviewTable("from UserTypeMenu as utm ,UserType as ut "+
                                      "where utm.UserType.userTypeId=ut.userTypeId"+
                                    " and ut.userTypeDesc like ' %"+ search +"%' ");
            Iterator ite = ll.iterator();
            while (ite.hasNext()) {
                UserTypeMenu obj = (UserTypeMenu) ite.next();
                data.add(obj);
            }  
            return data;
        }
```

my UserType entity class :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_type")
    public class UserType {
            @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "User_Type_Id")
        private Integer userTypeId;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "User_Type")
        private String userType;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "User_Type_Desc")
        private String userTypeDesc;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "Status")
        private String status;
          @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "Markers")
        private String markers;
    }
```

UserTypeMenu Entity class :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_type_menu")
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "UserTypeMenu.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM UserTypeMenu u")})
    public class UserTypeMenu implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "User_Type_Menu_Id")
        private Integer userTypeMenuId;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "Status")
        private String status;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "Markers")
        private String markers;
        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        private UserType userType;
        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        private UserMenuMaster userMenuMaster;
        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        private UserMenuBar userMenuBar;
    }
```

what i want is to get data from UsertypeMenu based on Usertype description.

please help me..
 thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't write joins in HQL like in SQL, you use `.` notation to navigate through object graph. Try this

```
"from UserTypeMenu as utm where utm.userType.userTypeDesc like ' %"+ search +"%' "
```

Actually, you can use joins but directly on associations. Here is the same query but using join syntax

```
"from UserTypeMenu as utm join utm.userType ut where ut.userTypeDesc like ' %"+ search +"%' "
```

The benefit of using joins here is that you can specify, for example, `left join` if the relation is not mandatory and you don't want to lose any results because of `inner join` which is implicitly used when you use `.`.

Comment: can you suggest me any site that will help me know more about hql in details.?? :)

Comment: Sure, best place for this is [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html). Of course, since HQL is an extension of JPQL you can also check the [JPQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html).

Comment: it is givimg me 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to EntityPack.UserTypeMenu 

this error.  at 
     UserTypeMenu obj = (UserTypeMenu) ite.next();
                data.add(obj);

Comment: You'll have to post the code of `pop.UrviewTable()`.

Comment: ' public List UrviewTable(String sQuery) {
   
            session = sf.sesFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query qee1 = session.createQuery(sQuery);
            List ll = qee1.list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
           
    }'

Comment: That should work, with the code you posted. Are you sure you are selecting only from `UserTypeMenu`? Try with simple query like `select utm from UserTypeMenu utm`. Also, debug the `while` loop and see what is the actual type returned by `ite.next()`

Comment: It is not working.. it is not returning me any data.. :( i tried simple queries. simple query works. `ite.next()` is not executed as it doent go inside the loops..

Comment: You can print out the generated SQL to check directly against the database if it returns any results. It should give you a good idea of what's wrong. Just turn on Hibernate's SQL logging.

Comment: I don't know how you configured Hibernate, but If you have `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, just add `<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>`, you'll see where it should go.